# DI in ASP.Net MVC6 view does braeking the MVC pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Today I came across a article which showed how we can call `DalService` class functionality from the view directly. Here is the article: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1315/aspnet-mvc-6-dependency-injection-views

The article shows that we can inject DalService by default DI and then we can call DalService functionality from the view directly.

Doesn't this break the MVC pattern ?

Was it possible in MVC 4/5 because in MVC 4/5 we can use unity DI and then we can call DalService from the view as shown in the linked article?

One new keyword has been introduced named `@inject DalService dService`

I'm looking for other suggestions.

Comment: Correct - this is a terrible idea. You would inject the DalService into the Controller and then pass a ViewModel to the view. The view certainly should not be calling any services and that article is non-sense in my humble opinion

Comment: if Microsoft offering this option in mvc core then people will use it and when Microsoft offering this then it has some usage......what u say?

Comment: Yep - don't worth this new `@inject` directive, consider it as syntax salt

Comment: @Mou You could conceivably have services that are view-oriented (i.e. a style service or such like, to grab colours or fonts?) which it would suit? But I would not use it for data access or business logic.

Comment: in asp.net mvc 4/5 can we do the same means can we inject something in view using unity DI as a result view can call service/ datalayer function directly ? if possible guide me how to achieve the same in asp.net mvc 4/5 ?